# How to set the antialias property for rgl in R?

Tags: r, antialiasing, rgl

I'm using the rgl package with R and trying to set the anti-aliasing option to my 3D plot. The following commands all return the same plot without anti-alias:

```
plot3d(X1,X2,X3, size=4)
plot3d(X1,X2,X3, size=4, antialias)
plot3d(X1,X2,X3, size=4, antialias=4)
plot3d(X1,X2,X3, size=4, rgl.antialias=3)
```

[image: The resulting plot]

How to properly set that option? I've read the manual for rgl but I can't find a clue. I know I can plot using cairo but this as far as I know will not give me interactive 3D plot so I can rotate it.

Thanks!!

Comment: See `?rgl_material`.  You probably need `point_antialias = TRUE`, but you can also add `line_antialias = TRUE` depending upon your needs.

Comment: @BryanHanson, First thank you for your hint. I had a look over     


rgl.material and I set both options as you mentioned. However, the point_antialias only turns points from square into circles and the line one has no visible effect (because I have no lines in this plot). So the axes (the cube) is not effected by line_antialias and the problem persist. Gnuplot can give fully antialiased interactive 3D plot, can't R?

Comment: Maybe look at the first argument in `?par3d`, that might make antialiasing universal.  I have usually drawn these things in pieces, for instance making my own axes where the antialias argument definitely works. I'm not sure what controls the appearance of the box - the docs imply the previous hint should work.  Also, try using `type = s` which will draw spheres rather than circles.

Comment: @BryanHanson, I think I figured it out thanks for your hint about ?par3d. The par3d has the antialias argument as ReadOnly, however open3d has it accessible. To have a full antialiased 3d plot one have to use open3d(antialias=4) first, or any other degree than 4. Then add the plot afterwards.

Comment: Excellent!  Onward with your project...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rgl package does allow full antialiasing but this have to be set using `open3d` command instead of the `plot3d` command. So for the case in question and assuming 4 degrees of AA, first call `open3d(antialias=4)`. Next call the plot command `plot3d(X1,X2,X3, size=4)` and the full AA plot will appear.

[image: AntiAliased 3D plot]